# Push Notifications Using Notification Hub and .NET Web API as Backend

Tags: ios, asp.net, iphone, asp.net-web-api, azure-notificationhub

I am working on a project where I have implemented web API with asp.net identity to authenticate users. An iPhone app will be accessing this web API in order to perform several tasks like authorization using identity db, subscribe to groups etc.

I am going to publish this web API in windows azure and going to use Azure notification hub for sending the notifications. Now in my iPhone app the user can subscribe to one or more groups to get notified to that group events. i.e A user can subscribe to "Cricket" and "Math" group in order to receive the notifications of that groups. So these groups really becomes Tags for the notification hub.

Now my question is There are two ways to register device to notification hub.

1) using app itself

2) using the web API that I have created.

I want to follow the second approach. I want the users devices to be registered to notification hub through my web API.

How can I achieve that? I didn't found any satisfactory code snippet for this purpose. Can any one provide me better clarification or code snippet on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can refer to the following link- http://www.ankitblog.com/2014/11/azure-notificationhub-sending-push.html and http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/845491/Azure-Notificationhub-Sending-Push-Notification-to for details of that. Its fairly simple